# How do I combine multiple user posts into one feed?

Tags: sql, django, feed, user-input

I'm using Django with Python (but I don't think that's relevant; I just need an idea of how to do this,) and I'm wondering how to combine posts from individual users into one feed. For example, user `a` is 'following' (subscribing to) people `b`, `c` and `d`. There are also other users such as `e`, which person `a` is not following. Other users, such as `b` and `c` can also follow other users. A user can follow no people, some people, or all people.

I want to select all posts by the people user `a` is following, in order of date. All the posts are stored in a PostgreSQL table called `user_post`, with the columns `id`, `user_id`, `content` and `time`.

Is there any way I can do this efficiently? I know websites like Twitter, tumblr, and Facebook do this. I'm not looking for a Python specific example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with the [`in` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#in).
You just need to get the id's of the users being followed, then query all posts with those users as an author. Here is some rough code considering I don't know your Model scheme.

```
following = active_user.following_set.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
posts = Post.objects.filter(author__in=following)
```